# Edit View Fields in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I am using 'Rails Admin' in my application. In my initializer I have the following in 'rails_admin.rb':

```
config.model "Player" do 
  edit do
    :name
    :team
    :shooting_percentage
  end
end
```

That gives me the following fields on the edit view in Rails Admin: name, team, and shooting percentage.

I would like to add two fields to the edit form in Rails Admin for Player but I don't want to make them as attributes on that model (or any model for that matter). I want to add shots, and goals as just form fields.

The reason I want to add those two form fields is so that I can use them to calculate the 'shooting_percentage' attribute value on Player.

Is there a way in Rails Admin to have fields on a form that are not fields on the model? Furthermore, if that is possible is there a way to use the values entered into those form fields to calculate a value for an actual model field (shooting percentage)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
class Player
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name,              type: String
  field :team,              type: String
  field :percentage,    type: Float    
  attr_accessor :shots, :goals

  before_save do
    self.percentage = shots.to_f / goals.to_f
  end

  rails_admin do
    configure :percentage do
      read_only true
    end
    edit do
      include_all_fields
      field :shots, :integer do
        html_attributes min: 1, required: true
        help 'number of shots'
      end
      field :goals, :integer do
        html_attributes min: 1, required: true
        help 'number of goals'
      end
    end
  end

end
```